# Openlayers 3 - Clustering & Lines as a combination

Tags: javascript, geocoding, openlayers-3

My aim is to cluster many coordinates in the view. This points also can have "connections" between them which I want to show as a LineString.

I tried a lot but I cannot find a way to integrate the Lines into the Cluster.

My current (stable) status can be seen here:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/467/)

```
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 20,
  source: vectorDevices
});
```

If the two points "merge" into the cluster it would be great if the conntection disappears or is part of the cluster itself.

Can anyone help me?

I tried to add the vectorLine as a source to the Cluster
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/468/)

```
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
  distance: 20,
  source: [vectorDevices, vectorLine]
});
```

or via addFeature 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RS2z/469/)

```
clusterSource.addFeature(vectorLine);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can add lines to a cluster currently. Openlayers 3 (as of v 3.14.2) clustering only allows you to cluster points. If you look at the source of ol.source.Cluster, there is a statement that asserts all features in it need to be points. 
(from https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.14.2/src/ol/source/clustersource.js)

```
ol.source.Cluster.prototype.createCluster_ = function(features) {
  var length = features.length;
  var centroid = [0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var geometry = features[i].getGeometry();
    goog.asserts.assert(geometry instanceof ol.geom.Point,
        'feature geometry is a ol.geom.Point instance');
    var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
    ol.coordinate.add(centroid, coordinates);
  }
  ol.coordinate.scale(centroid, 1 / length);

  var cluster = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(centroid));
  cluster.set('features', features);
  return cluster;
};
```

I think your best bet would be to change the visibility of the line layer to false somehow when the points are clustered.

Edit: However this may change in the next version of ol, a pull request (https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4917) has been merged which has a geometryFunction option.